# CSS a-Tag Linkcolor: Particular change for a class

Tags: html, css, class

I have declared a CSS attribute for the main-container of a HTML page. Now I want an ahref-button to have another color, but it is not applied without `!important`. Therefore I want ask you how I can do that.

Thank you!

See also: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKXRNg)

```
main a:link, main a:visited { 
  color: black; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.test {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 190px;
    display: block;
    color: white; /*is not applied*/
}

/*Another try*/
a.test {
  color: white; /*is not applied, however it is with !important. But this shouldn't be the right solution?*/
}
<main>
  <a href="/link" class="test">Button</a>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `:link` in  `main.a:link` or style more specific `main a.test` with your color. I try to remove it and working as well